# Magento 2 : Most of the Links are not working after upgrade and compile in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, setup-di-compile, dicompilation

Most of the Links are not working after upgrade and compile in magento 2.1

**Like wish list, Add to Compare, edit/Delete product on cart page, Compare menu** etc.

Is there any solution ?

The href links coming with hash (#).

Kindly help.

Comment: Did you run static content deploy and set proper permission?

Comment: yes i did the static-content-deploy and cache:flush. access right of pub folder 775. and all inside folder has 777 access rights

Comment: now set the permission  of pub folder 755. and all inside folder has 755 access rights and for file 775

Comment: not work @sukumar Gorai

Comment: please check form key in every add/edit cart and wish list Compare form